# Photo's filename weird numbers

Tags: photos, files, date-and-time

I have an android phone. When I tried to connected it to my PC and opened image folder (DCIM/101SHARP), I have found many photos.
There is a photo with the name ".trashed-1666704779-DSC_0328.JPG".
At first I thought "1666704779" is unix timestamp, but it doesn't seem so, because when I converted it into a date, it was a date in the future.
Can someone tell what "1666704779" stands for, if it actually has any meanings. Thanks!

Comment: Does that file really matter? It is a hidden file. It has "trash" in its name. It is probably meant to be discarded. As for creation date, use your file manager, show hidden files, and see properties for that file. You might be able to see creation date or last modification date. You should also be able to open it in an image viewer (or rename it first by removing the first dot).

Comment: @Firelord I don't want to know creation/modification date, I just want to know what is the meaning behind that number if there is any

Comment: File naming schemes are dependent on the app which created them. There is no standard as in what naming convention to follow. You can ask the developer of the app for the naming convention their app is using. You can increase your chances of getting an answer here by mentioning the name of the app which created that file.